# Basic query related to conditional expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

I have two variables $X$ and $Y$. I want to find the following probability $$P(X>a(Y+c),X+Y>d)$$
where $a>0,c>0,d>0$. To find the solution I have done following steps  $$E_Y[P(X>a(Y+c),X>d-Y)]$$
where expectation is with respect to $Y$. Now we can split the above expression in two parts depending on the event $a(Y+c)>d-Y$. Hence, we can write
$$E_{Y|Y>\frac{d-ac}{a+1}}[P(X>a(Y+c))]P(Y>\frac{d-ac}{a+1})+E_{Y|Y<\frac{d-ac}{a+1}}[P(X>d-y)]P(Y<\frac{d-ac}{a+1})$$
I want to know if the above expression is right or the expression given below $$E_{Y}[P(X>a(Y+c))]P(Y>\frac{d-ac}{a+1})+E_{Y}[P(X>d-y)]P(Y<\frac{d-ac}{a+1})$$
The difference is the use of conditional expectation in the first expression while unconditional expectation in the second expression. In my own understanding I think the first expression is correct. However, I have seen in a paper that authors used second expression therefore I am quite confused. Please provide some insights over it. Thank you.

The image from the paper. [image]

Comment: Let $b=\frac{d-ac}{a+1}$ then $$[X>a(Y+c),X+Y>d]=[X>a(Y+c),Y>b]\cup[X>d-Y,Y\leqslant b]$$ hence $$P(X>a(Y+c),X+Y>d)=P(X>a(Y+c),Y>b)+P(X>d-Y,Y\leqslant b).$$ Now, taking the first part of the decomposition as an example, it is a fact that $$P(X>a(Y+c),Y>b)=P(X>a(Y+c)\mid Y>b)P(Y>b).$$ As long as one sticks to these (basic) definitions, no trouble can ensue. Formulas such as $$E_{Y\mid Y>b}(P(X>a(Y+c)))$$ on the other hand, are to be avoided, since $P(X>a(Y+c))$ is actually a *number*, hence $$E_{Y\mid Y>b}(P(X>a(Y+c)))=P(X>a(Y+c)),$$ which is not the quantity $$P(X>a(Y+c)\mid Y>b)$$ one wants.

Comment: @Did what i understood from your comment is that the second expression in my OP is incorrect however the notation for the first expression is also incorrect. But the main thing is that the second expression is incorrect because expectation over $Y$ is being taken over all possible values of $Y$.

Comment: @Did I have a little problem in understanding your comment part where you have written "since $P(X>a(Y+c))$ is actually a number". I understand that it is a number for a fixed value of $Y$ but this is not the case here because $Y$ can assume values $>b$ with some probability. Please provide some insights to help me in understanding this. Thank you.

Comment: The probability can be viewed as the expectation of the corresponding indicator. So you use the indicator if you insist on expressing it as the double expectation formula.

Comment: Notations matter. By definition, $P(X>a(Y+c))=P(A)$ where $A=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)>a(Y(\omega)+c)\}$ hence $P(X>a(Y+c))$ is a number. If you want to denote something different from $P(A)$, do not use the notation $P(X>a(Y+c))$. Sorry but I fail to see what more there is to explain. The phrase "it is a number for a fixed value of Y" simply does not parse.

Comment: @Did I can understand the definition of the event $A$ but this definition does not,in my understanding, take into account the condition that $Y(\omega)>b$. Please ignore my this comment if I am wrong again. Thank you Did for your help.

Comment: Indeed the event $A=\{X>a(Y+c)\}$ does not "take into account the condition that" $Y>b$. If one wants to "take into account" this condition, one can consider the event $A'=\{X>a(Y+c),Y>b\}$.

Comment: @Did So the actual problem is notation. Although I have seen papers that use this notation. One example is provided above as an image. In my understanding the last equation is wrong (here $v, \sigma, \sigma_c, T, \hat{\phi}$ are constants). Please comment if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: Indeed this computation is wrong (on several accounts). One is looking at $P(A)$ where $$A=\{S>u(I),S>v(I)\},$$ and one knows that the functions $u$ and $v$ are such that $u(x)\geqslant v(x)$ for every $x>\mu$ and $u(x)<v(x)$ for every $x\leqslant\mu$. Then $$P(A)=P(A,I>\mu)+P(A,I\leqslant\mu)=P(S>u(I),I>\mu)+P(S>v(I),I\leqslant\mu)$$ which is also $$P(A)=P(S>u(I)\mid I>\mu)P(I>\mu)+P(S>v(I)\mid I\leqslant\mu)P(I\leqslant\mu)$$ but certainly not $$P(S>u(I))P(I>\mu)+P(S>v(I))P(I\leqslant\mu).$$ Source of the paper?

Comment: @Did this is from "Milimeter wave energy harvesting". I think it is not published yet but its accepted in IEEE Trans. on wirel. communictions and it is available on the IEEE Xplore site. The particular image is from its last appendix. Thank you so much Did for clarifying my confusion.

Comment: @Did can this be considered a big mistake for which a correspondence should be made or its not worth it?

Comment: If the mistake has concrete consequences on the results of the paper, yes. If this is just a slip of the authors' pen, localized to the appendix, then no.